# Subsea galvanic corrosion protection by paint

Tags: materials, steel

In submerged conditions galvanic corrosion effects exist between metals with dissimilar nobleness and the presence of seawater as electrolyte.

Does reducing the contact area by using an nonconducting paint *on the interface layer between the two metal parts* help delay this process? Or is any the solid contact electrical route, e.g. via a bolt or so, enough to make the deterioration speed limited by the electrolytic process c.q. the surface area in contact with the electrolyte?

Comment: Your use of c.q. here is unclear; can you edit to use a more universally understood phrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No solid contact is required at all, as the seawater provides the electrical route. In order to prevent galvanic corrosion, you would need to electrically isolate your two metals. That said, I can see that a solid electrical route would allow faster transfer of electrons, speeding up corrosion, and hence having no solid electrical route would delay corrosion.

Comment: Ok tnx! so no solid contact at al! I found this definition "electrochemical action of two dissimilar metals in the presence
of an electrolyte *and an electron conductive path*" Apparently is the seawater at $\approx 0.2\,[\Omega/m]$ both electrolyte and path.